# changing some rows from data.frame, when there are 2 logical conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

For example,

```
Name <- c("Ben", "Dana", "Ben", "Ellen", "Ellen", "Ben", "Ben", "George")
Date <- c(2016-12-02, 2015-03-03, 2014-05-03, 2010-05-05,
          2016-02-02, 2015-03-04, 2014-05-08, 2010-06-05)
Type <- c("ES pp", "ES pr", "ES pp", "LT pp", "LT pp", "ES pp", "LT pp", "LT pp")
mydata <- data.frame(Name, Date, Type)
```

If `mydata$Name=="Ben" & mydata$Type=="ES pp"`, I want to change `"ES pp"` to `"LT pr"` for example. When I call `mydata` next time, I want it always stay the way I have changed it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The way your example `mydata` is written, `Type` is a factor, which makes the solution more difficult.

Let's suppose you did not mean that, and that `Type` is not supposed to be a factor:

```r
mydata <- data.frame(Name, Date, Type, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> mydata
    Name Date  Type
1    Ben 2002 ES pp
2   Dana 2009 ES pr
3    Ben 2006 ES pp
4  Ellen 2000 LT pp
5  Ellen 2012 LT pp
6    Ben 2008 ES pp
7    Ben 2001 LT pp
8 George 1999 LT pp
```

Then you could use your conditional to index the variable in the data frame, and replace the value.

```
mydata$Type[mydata$Name == 'Ben' & mydata$Type == 'ES pp'] <- 'LT pr'

> mydata
Name Date  Type
1    Ben 2002 LT pr
2   Dana 2009 ES pr
3    Ben 2006 LT pr
4  Ellen 2000 LT pp
5  Ellen 2012 LT pp
6    Ben 2008 LT pr
7    Ben 2001 LT pp
8 George 1999 LT pp
```

Now, if you *did* intend for `Type` to be a factor, then you have the problem that `'LT pr'` is not one of your factor levels, at least not the way your example is written. For now I'm going to hope this is not what you meant, because solving that is much messier, and I think a distraction from the point of your question.